# How to validate a single value but not annotated pojo with specific ConstraintValidator in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, bean-validation

My purpose is to use a specific ConstraintValidator in 2 scenarios below

1. use annotations on POJO to validate the whole object (the popular way)
2. validate a single value with specific validator's isValid function (for some configurable dynamic validation request)

The validator must support services injection, so I must get it from spring but not create a new validator instance manually.

followed my test codes:

annotation

```java
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER, TYPE_USE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = { IdNumberValidator.class })
public @interface IdNumber {

    String message() default "id number is not available";

    Class<?>[] groups() default { };

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };

}
```

validator

```java
public class IdNumberValidator implements ConstraintValidator<IdNumber, String>, BeanNameAware {

    @Autowired
    private IUserService usrService;

    private String bn;

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context){
        System.out.println("my name is:" + bn);
        return usrService.getUserByAccount(value).isPresent();
    }

    @Override
    public void setBeanName(String name) {
        this.bn = name;
    }
}
```

pojo

```java
@Getter
@Setter
public class TestPOJO {

    private long id;

    @IdNumber
    private String idn;
}
```

service

```java
@Service
public class TestValidatorService {

    @Autowired
    private Validator validator;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    public void validatePojo(TestPOJO pojo){
        BeanPropertyBindingResult e = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(pojo, "TestPOJO");
        validator.validate(pojo, e);
        if(e.hasErrors()){
            for(ObjectError oe : e.getAllErrors()){
                System.out.println(oe.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    public void validatePojoByDynamicValidator(TestPOJO pojo){
        IdNumberValidator validator = context.getBean("com.test.IdNumberValidator", IdNumberValidator.class);  // got the name via BeanNameAware but seems not working
        System.out.println(validator.isValid(pojo.getIdn(), null));
    }
}
```

In the test case for service, function "validatePojo" passed but "validatePojoByDynamicValidator" did not.

Any solution for this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Just get the bean by type not by name. Or in short, just remove the name from the `getBean`. Also that isn't the name of the bean, the name would be `idNumberValidator`.

Comment: I have tried getBean with class and failed with Exception:
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.test.IdNumberValidator' available

Comment: Well than it isn't available. Did you place `@Component` on it? Else it won't be created as a bean. Also i would recommend against this and just use plain JSR303 validation for this and if you want to validate only certain things use validation groups to limit the scope. Instead of working around that.

Comment: I add @Component annotation to the validator and it works! Thanks Deinum!
I found that the validator has two component instances, that means it's not the bean which is used by validator framework, but it doesn't matter.